# Is possible to execute 2 or more windows (Tk) of turtle at the same time from the same code?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Since make one drawing with two turtles at the same time in 1 tk window dont work very well, i was wondering if its easier to draw each part of the drawing in a diferent window at the same time.

Ex :

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import random

screen = Screen()
t = Turtle(visible=False)
t.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

def got(x,y,d) :
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    t.seth(d)


def tuneis(ragn):
    d=0
    for i in range(ragn):

        got(0,0,d)  
        d = d + 10
        t.penup()

        t.forward(400)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(500)

tuneis(36)
real = []

def realidade(ragn) :
    d=5
    for i in range(ragn):
        b = random.randint(10,50)
        t.pensize(b)
        t.color('green')
        got(0,0,d)  
        real.append(b)
        d = d + 10
        t.penup()

        t.forward(450)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(500)

realidade(36)

def filo(x,y):
        cont = x        
        t.color('green')
        for i in real:

            t.pensize(0)
            #b=random.randint(10,50)

            got(cont,y,0)
            cont = cont + 10

            t.setheading(270)
            t.forward(i)
        y= y + 20
        cont = cont - (len(real)*10 / 2)
        d=0
        for i in real :
            got(cont,y,d)
            t.forward(i)
            d=d+5


filo(-200,300)
```

Would be possible to draw "tuneis" and "realidade" in one window, and "filo" in another window at the same time ?

Comment: I see a flaw in this plan: `filo()` depends on the array `real` which `realidade()` assembles so how can `filo()` and `realidade()` run at the same time?  They might be able to operate like coroutines with `realidade()` feeding `filo()` data via `yield` or some such.  But this isn't really about having multiple turtles doing independent drawing at the same time.

Comment: I don't know if you can create two windows with turtle but I think with two windows it will work the same way. Both windows will use the same `mainloop()` as with one window. If you will run two `mainloop()` then only one of them will work and second will wait till you close first `mainloop()`